# Kotlin JavaScript Engine implementation

Tags: javascript, kotlin

Does anyone know which JavaScript engine Kotlin is using to evaluate Javascript? I found the following class

```
KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineFactoryExamples.kt
```

looking at the class source [KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineFactoryExamples.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-script-util/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/script/jsr223/KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineFactoryExamples.kt) could see the following dependency

```
import javax.script.Bindings
import javax.script.ScriptContext
import javax.script.ScriptEngine
```

I'm wondering whether Kotlin is based on already existing Javascript Engines like Nashorn or Rhino or it's running its own implementation. I'm considering to port my lib to Korlin, the performance is extremely important for me, base on my tests Hashorn is losing to Rhino. So I want to find out, what engine Kotlin is executing behind the senses.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kotlin and Javascript are just languages. When you compile kotlin to javascript, it is translated to a javascript file and you can use the javascript file anywhere directly.

Comment: Thanks for replying, my intention was to figure out not how Kotlin is interpreted to JS but what lib it is using when I need to eval JS static code from Kotlin. I don't believe Kotlin does with it something, I wouldn't expect to see some JS engine, like Rhino for JAVA

Comment: What do you mean by "eval JS static code from Kotlin"? The js() function supporting inline JavaScript is only available in Kotlin/JS. Kotlin/JVM and Kotlin/Native do not have any features for evaluating JS code.

Comment: according to the doc http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support the javascript could be eval not only using js()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript engine is provided by JDK. It can be:

- Rhino before JDK 8
- Nashorn [since JDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/174)
- Deprecated [since JDK 11](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335)

You can find out script engine for your JDK using:

```
val engine = javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript")

println(engine::class) // class jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine
```

Comment: Please advice on which script engine one can use now, after Nashorn has been deprecated in JDK 11? @kzm